# mongo copy from one collection to another (on the same db)

Tags: mongodb

I have got mongo db called `test` and in this db two collections `collection1` and `collection1_backup`.
How to replace content of `collection1` with data from `collection1_backup`.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The best way to have done this (considering the name of the collection ends with `_backup`) is possibly to have used mongorestore: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongorestore/

However in this case it depends. If the collection is unsharded you can use `renameCollection` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/ ) or you can use a more manual method of (in JavaScript code):

```
db.collection1.drop(); // Drop entire other collection
db.collection1_backup.find().forEach(function(doc){
   db.collection1.insert(doc); // start to replace
});
```

Those are the most common methods of doing this.

Comment: Slowest method as opposed to aggregation.

Comment: @DenisDenisov have you got any proof of that? I would imagine that the two (manual method and aggregation framework, this method would definitely not be faster than the copy function that's actually specifically designed to copy tables, though it might be considering the safety measures it might take) would copy relatively the same, they would need to read all rows into active working set and then save them back down, I don't really see how the aggregation framework would be faster, not to mention that it isn't really designed for such a thing

Comment: Yes, I've just checked on a large collection. Collection and indexes use `wiredTiger.configString='block_compressor=zstd'`. Aggregation was almost instantly executed by `percona-server-mongodb-server-4.2.6-6.el7.x86_64`.

Comment: @DenisDenisov instnatly? Even on a collection of 2m records another user records about 3 minutes https://stackoverflow.com/a/37870870/383478 and instantly is faster than the disk can actually write, so that defies the laws of science

Comment: Anyway, `db.collection1_backup.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "collection1" } ])` works faster that. `find().forEach(..insert`=~100rec/s https://forums.meteor.com/t/iterating-over-mongo-cursor-too-slow-server-side/19531/13 https://mongobooster.useresponse.com/topic/slow-performance-using-foreach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31466623/mongodb-foreach-vs-fetch-each

Comment: @DenisDenisov `$out` pipeline is different from copy or in this case it would be a `$merge` which is way slower and wont replace the complete output target collection data at the end.

Comment: @DenisDenisov I just noticed your comment, I thin you mistake something with my answer for one, you are quoting a disparate app using meteor (for some reason) as a response, it's not really, this can be run on the same server as the actual collection itself and will use the built in driver (not the nodejs one) for the js console

Answer (score 26):

This can be done using this simple command:

```
db.collection1_backup.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "collection1" } ])
```

This command will remove all the documents of `collection1` and then make a clone of `collection1_backup` in collection1.

Generic Command would be

```
db.<SOURCE_COLLECTION>.aggregate([ { $match: {} }, { $out: "<TARGET_COLLECTION>" } ])
```

If `TARGET_COLLECTION` does not exist, the above command will create it.

Comment: This answer should actually be the accepted answer

Answer (score 6):

also usefull:
to export collection to json file

```
mongoexport --collection collection1_backup --out collection1.json
```

to import collection from json file

```
mongoimport --db test --collection collection1 --file collection1.json
```

to import single collection from backup/dump file one need to convert *.bson file to *.json 
by using

```
bsondump collection1_backup.bson > collection1_backup.json
```

Comment: In general it is preferable to use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` when copying collections, as converting documents to JSON and back may affect the [data type fidelity](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/import-export/#data-type-fidelity). There are some data types that exist in BSON that can have a [different representation in JSON](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON) where there is no strict JSON equivalent.  Use of `mongoimport`/`mongoexport` may be OK depending on your data, but this is an important caveat to be aware of.

Comment: @Stennie It's also important to note that doing a mongodump / mongorestore will preserve indexes. So, if you're trying to duplicate docs between collections, you won't be able to restore. 

mongoexport and mongoimport should be used if you're trying to duplicate docs between collections.

Comment: @ivandov You can skip recreating indexes (aside from the required `_id` index) with `mongorestore  --noIndexRestore`.  Note that `mongorestore` (as at MongoDB 3.4) only does inserts; if a document with the same `_id` exists, it will not be updated or replaced. The `mongoimport` tool supports upserts (and in 3.4, merges), but works with text formats rather than MongoDB's native BSON format. `mongodump` and `mongorestore` are still the recommended options if you want to recreate data (and optionally, collection metadata) identically between MongoDB deployments.

Answer (score 2):

simply just do this.

//drop collection1

```
db.collection1.drop();
```

//copy data from collection1_backup to collection1

```
db.collection1.insert(db.collection1_backup.find({},{_id:0}).toArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Java Driver

Try below one:

```java
public void copyTo(String db,String sourceCollection,String destinationCollection,int limit) throws        
UnknownHostException {

    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB database = mongo.getDB(db);
    DBCollection collection = database.getCollection(sourceCollection);
    DBCursor dbCursor = collection.find().limit(limit);
    List<DBObject> list =  dbCursor.toArray();
    DBCollection destination =  database.getCollection(destinationCollection);
    destination.insert(list, WriteConcern.NORMAL); //WRITE CONCERN is based on your requirment.

}
```

Comment: Using `import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;` I add to translate to : 
`MongoCollection<Document> database = template.getCollection("database");
List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
database.find().iterator().forEachRemaining(documents::add);

MongoCollection<Document> destination = template.getCollection("destination");
destination.insertMany(documents);

database.drop();`

Answer (score 1):

Better way would be to use [`.toArray()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/)

```
 db.collection1.drop(); // Drop entire other collection

 // creates an array which can be accessed from "data"
 db.collection1_backup.find().toArray(function(err, data) {

      // creates a collection and inserting the array at once
      db.collection1.insert(data);
 });
```

Comment: What about size optimization? If my collection is 2GB should I have 2GB RAM?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple command to Backup MongoDB Collection. It will work only on **MongoDB 4.0 or earlier versions**.

```
db.sourceCollectionName.copyTo('targetCollectionName')
```

**Your targetCollectionName must be in Single(') or Double(") Quote**

Note:

> The db.collection.copyTo() method uses the eval command internally. As
> a result, the db.collection.copyTo() operation takes a global lock
> that blocks all other read and write operations until the
> db.collection.copyTo() completes.

Comment: [`copyTo`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) may require some [special permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128079/mongo-copy-collection-and-user-permissions) and may also alter data when converting from BSON to JSON.

Comment: copyTo was deprecated: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/. Quote:
"Starting in version 4.2, MongoDB removes the eval command. The deprecated db.collection.copyTo(), which wraps the eval command, can only be run against MongoDB 4.0 or earlier versions. For behavior and example, refer to the 4.0 or earlier version of the manual."

Answer (score 0):

Drop collection1

then use this query

```
var cursor = db.collection1_backup.find();
var data = [];
while(cursor.hasNest()){
    data.push(cursor.next());
}

db.collection1.insertMany(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run this simple query...

```
db.collection1.insertMany(db.collection1_backup.find({}).toArray())
```

Run this simple query to copy all the data from **collection1_backup** collection to **collection1** collection.