# Mongo Copy Collection and User Permissions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to copy a collection through the shell, but I am getting an 'unauthorized' error, despite having read/write permissions. Specifically:

```
db.createCollection("ITISAFAKE")

{ "ok" : 1 }

db.ITISAFAKE.insert({"Is it a fake?": true})

db.ITISAFAKE.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d5e51d4bb0851f985f69d8"), "Is it a fake?" : true }

db.ITISAFAKE.drop()

true
```

Yay that works fine. However:

```
db.createCollection("FAKE") 

{ "ok" : 1 }

db.FAKE.insert({senator: true})

db.FAKE.copyTo("FAKERY")

Tue Jan 14 17:36:26.188 { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" } at src/mongo/shell/db.js:571
```

So, I could solve this problem by literally copying things over record by record, but that seems dumb. I can fiddle with user permissions etc, but how do I ... actually just copy things?

Answer (score 6):

Per the [`collection.copyTo()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) documentation in MongoDB 2.4, this shell helper "copies all documents from collection into newCollection using server-side JavaScript".

I expect the reason you are getting an `unauthorized` error is because the server-side [`db.eval()` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) requires [full admin permissions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/#combined-access) in MongoDB 2.4 (multiple roles on the `admin` database).

You can actually see the source for this helper in the `mongo` shell if you invoke `copyTo()` without the `()`:

```
> db.test.copyTo
function ( newName ){
    return this.getDB().eval(
        function( collName , newName ){
            var from = db[collName];
            var to = db[newName];
            to.ensureIndex( { _id : 1 } );
            var count = 0;

            var cursor = from.find();
            while ( cursor.hasNext() ){
                var o = cursor.next();
                count++;
                to.save( o );
            }

            return count;
        } , this.getName() , newName
    );
}
```

Due to the use of server-side `db.eval()`, there are [several significant warnings](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) on `copyTo()` usage including cautions on type fidelity and locking issues. I believe this helper is only intended to be used in development environments with more open permissions, rather than a production environment.

#### DIY copy from the `mongo` shell

> So, I could solve this problem by literally copying things over record by record

That's not an entirely crazy option :). Here is a simple one-liner for the `mongo` shell (replace `source` and `target` collections as appropriate):

```
db.source.find().forEach( function(d) {db.target.insert(d)});
```

If you are concerned about network bandwidth you can run this from a `mongo` shell which is local to your MongoDB server.

#### Copy with `mongodump` / `mongorestore`

A better approach to copying a collection (although not directly from the `mongo` shell) would be to use `mongodump` & `mongorestore`:

```
$ mongodump -d test -c source 
$ mongorestore -d test -c target dump/test/source.bson
```