# Copying a mongo collection with huge data to another collection?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a mongo collection(s) with 2.5 million data and that may grow upto 3 million. I am using spring batch and am trying to copy that collection to another collection. Approaches I have used are as follows :

- Inside a tasklet, I have Created a ProcessBuilder object and called a shell script which executes a mongo query. Content of shell script is as follows :

  ```
  >  mongo $serverURL/$dbName js-file-to-execute.js

  // js file contains copy command (db.collection.copyto('newCollection'))
  ```

For less data (< 200 k) it works fine but for 2 million data it hangs the mongo server and the job got failed with Socket Exception

- Used a mongo template and executed a query

`dbMongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection("collection").aggregate(Arrays.asList((DBObject) new BasicDBObject("$out","newCollection")));`

This executes a mongo aggregate query `db.collection.aggregate({$out : "newCollection"})`

This also worked for collections with less data but for larger data set it keeps running until socket time out occurs and fails the job at the end.

Please suggest efficient way to copy data?

Comment: What version and storage engine are you using? What is the structure of the MongoDB cluster: standalone, replica set, sharded? Are you looking for the fastest solution (wall clock), uses  the least extra resources (disk and/or memory), or lowest impact to the server (e.g., don't hang the server).

Comment: I am using **mongodb 2.6** and mongoDB cluster is **standalone**. I would  prefer a balancing solution which do use significant amount of time with average impact on server.

Comment: Did profesor79's answer helped u? Im in the same situation

Comment: Yes it helps but instead of mongodump and mongorestore you can use mongo import and mongo export. Also you can pipe these operations for inline copying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy this collection I will sugest using mongodump/mongoexport

> mongodump --db databaseName --collection collectionName  --out directory-path

then copy directory `directory-path` and then restore on target machine using

> mongorestore --db databaseName --collection collectionName directory-path

Answer (score 8):

```
//Fastest way to copy a Collection in MongoDB
db.getCollection('OriginalCollection').aggregate([ { $out: "ClonedCollection" } ]);
```

This command copied a collection of 2 million records in about 2-3 minutes.

https://gist.github.com/tejzpr/ff37324a8c26d13fef08c318278c0718

Comment: Hi, I need to copy the collection A records containing 100k datasets to collection B containing million datasets. In this case when i use the above query will it cause any performance problem and I am having index on the Collection B for fast reads.I am using 3.2.1 Mongodb

Comment: Thanks a lot for the trick! 2-3 minutes - it's an open question, I guess it depends on the size of the collection. In my case, 2.3M records (~9Gib storage size) took ~25 minutes.