# Error trying to copy collection to another collection using aggregate.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, eval, mean-stack

I'm new to MEAN stack and i'm trying to copy the whole data from one collection to another.I have written an API in nodejs using eval function with mongodb package(v2.2.33) to achieve it, but that blocks the application.After searching and going through docs, got to know that i should use "aggregate" function. Which works fine with mongodb server console, but not in nodejs API. It says TypeError: aggregate is not defined.

This is my API:

```
    router.get('/movedata', function(req,res,next){

    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/new_db", function (err, 
    db) {


    db.Persons123.aggregate([{ $out: "mycopy"}]);


    // db.eval(function(err) {
    //  if(err) throw err;

    //    db.quotation_dummy_collections.copyTo("quotations");


    //    db.quotation_dummy_collections.remove( { } );

    // } );



   })

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need the collection object, something like this:

```
router.get('/movedata', function(req,res,next){

    MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/new_db", function (err, 
    db) {


const personsCollection = db.collection('Persons123');
personsCollection.aggregate([{ $out: "mycopy"}]);
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Now it's not showing the TypeError for the aggregate function,but not copying the collection data to another.

Answer (score 1):

The commands for MongoDB's server console don't apply exactly to the node.js driver. For your version, refer to the documentation here- http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/

For the problem with your code. Try this-

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/new_db", function(err, db) {
   if(err){
       console.log(err);
   }
   else{
       var collection = db.collection("Persons123");
       collection.aggregate([{
           $out:'"mycopy"'
       }]).toArray(function(err,items){
           if(err){
               console.log(err);
           }
           else{
               console.log(items);
           }
       });
   }
});
```

Comment: now it is creating the collection, but passing the empty array.

Comment: Yes, but if you check the new collection all the documents have been copied.

Answer (score 1):

After going through all the related questions in stackoverflow. I found a way to solve the issue. This link helped me [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916004/mongo-copy-from-one-collection-to-another-on-the-same-db/13916163](http://Here)

This is my code:

```
    const pp = db.collection('quotation_dummy_collections');
    const pp01 = db.collection('quotations');


    pp.find().forEach(function(doc){
    pp01.insert(doc); 
    pp.remove({});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these methods inside MongoClient code:

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/", function (error, mongo) {
    if (error) throw error;
    
    let db = mongo.db("new_db");
    let persons = db.collection("Persons123");
    
    persons.aggregate([], { out: "mycopy"}, 
        function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            
            console.log(result);
            mongo.close();
        }
    );
});
```

OR

```
persons.aggregate([], { out: "mycopy"});
```

OR

```
persons.aggregate([{ out: "mycopy"}]);
```

OR

```
persons.aggregate([{ $out: "mycopy"}]);
```

- Got from documentation: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html

- If it still does not work, you may try personal code of mine:
  https://github.com/matszrmn/NodeJS_Copy_Collection