# What is the best way to archive history data in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongo that stores every user action of my application, and its very huge in size (3Million documents per day). On UI I have a requirement to show the user actions for max. 6months period.

And the queries on this collection are becoming very slow with all the historic data, though there are indexes in place. So, I want to move the documents that are older than 6months to a separate collection.

Is it the right way to handle my issue?

Comment: @ Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916004/mongo-copy-from-one-collection-to-another-on-the-same-db

Comment: hi Kanishk, my question is not about how to copy data from one collection to other the collection, but I want to know the best way of archiving data.

Comment: @VenkatPapana if you want to archive your data by moving documents to a separate collection, then the first step is to copy it (followed by a second step to delete it from the original collection). The answers in the question linked by kanishk tanwar should be useful to you.

Comment: @VinceBowdren, I want to know if there are any other options available to archive mongo data other than moving documents into a separate collection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following are some of the techniques you can use to manage data growth in MongoDB:

- Using capped collection
- Using TTLs
- Using mulitple collections for months
- Using different databases on same host

Answer (score -1):

The best ways is **Online Archive**.

It comes with a cost: M10 cluster or higher as Online Archive is currently not available for the shared tiers.

1. Access our cluster details
2. Go to the "Online Archive" Tab
3. Configure your Archive rule. (wizard guided)
4. Confirm in the button. The documents that match the rules will start being
   archived.

More official details here:

- https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/atlas/atlas-data-lake-online-archive/
- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/online-archive/manage-online-archive/