# Mongo historic of 10 documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a `stuffs-historic` collection that stores `stuff` documents. I want to have the last `10 stuffs` stored in this collection, and when saving a new `stuff`, it should replace the oldest one if there is already 10 stuffs saved. Is it possible to do it in a more optimized way? I managed to do that with the following steps:

1. Get all `stuffs` i have in `stuffs-history` with the given `stuff-id` sorting by date
2. If the array length returned is less than 10, I [copy the `stuff` to `stuffs-historic`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916004/mongo-copy-from-one-collection-to-another-on-the-same-db)
3. If not, i replace the oldest.

Comment: Is [capped collection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/capped-collections/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Not actually because i can have only 10 of that `stuff-id`, not 10 maximum for the entire collection

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, a capped collection would be the best starting point. Here's an example using the node driver:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/local'

const client = new MongoClient(uri)
const run = async () => {
  try {
    await client.connect()

    const db = client.db('local')
    await db.createCollection('capped', { capped: true, size: 10 }) // 10 = bytes, not records
    const capped = db.collection('capped')

    await capped.deleteMany()

    let counter = 0
    while (counter <= 30) {
      await capped.insertOne({ counter: counter++ })
      const current = (await capped.find().toArray()).map(d => d.counter).join(', ')
      console.log('records ->', current)
    }

    await db.dropCollection('capped')
  } finally {
    await client.close()
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir)
```

It will create a capped collection (with a capacity of 10 bytes - not 10 records), then insert 31 records, but the collection will only ever have a max of 10 bytes stored. The oldest records are the first to be evicted. After each insert, I log the documents in the collection to prove that the size is max of 10 and the oldest are evicted first.

Example output:

```
records -> 1
records -> 1, 2
records -> 1, 2, 3
records -> 1, 2, 3, 4
records -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
records -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
records -> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
records -> 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
records -> 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
records -> 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
records -> 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11
records -> 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
records -> 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
records -> 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14
records -> 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15
records -> 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16
records -> 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17
records -> 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18
records -> 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19
records -> 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
records -> 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21
records -> 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22
records -> 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23
records -> 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24
records -> 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25
records -> 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26
records -> 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27
records -> 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28
records -> 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
records -> 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
```

In order to get the exact number of records back, make the collection larger than you need it to be (you will have to work out how big this will be in bytes), and the ObjectID (assuming that you use the default), will give you insertion order, so you can reverse sort on that and limit your results, eg:

```
db.capped.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(5)
```